# Unix Sort Merge Workaround

Tags: sorting, unix, memory, merge

I have around five-hundred 23M files of data that I am trying to sort into one database. I have sorted them all individually using `sort`, and am now trying to merge them using `sort --merge`, so that the whole sample is sorted together. Then I plan to split them up into five-hundred files again.

The issue I am running into is that my drive is very congested, and I only have about 805GB available according to `df`. When I run `sort --merge file1 file2 file3...` I eventually receive an error that sort has failed due to no more space left on the drive.

Are there any tips for how I could work around or solve this issue, or is the only solution to free up more space?

Comment: 500 files, 23 MB each, makes about 11.5 GB. That should certainly fit into a free space of over 800 GB. Possibly the sort says it's out of files, i.e. it is unable to handle 5 hundred simultaneous input files? In such case I would try to merge them in smaller chunks (say, 25 files at a time), then merge resulting 20 files together.

Comment: What sort of system do you have? How much space is there in the filesystem that /tmp is on? Sort will use temp files, and it's possible you're just out of space in that partition.